# Multi collection filter in mongodb in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have 3 different collection `Recipe`, `Category` and `Cuisines`.

> Relationship between them

Each `Recipe`(n) <=======> (n) `Category` each recipe can have many `Category` also each categories can have many recipes.

Each `Recipe` (n) <======> (n) `Cuisines` each recipe can have many cuisines also each cuisines can have many recipes.

`Recipe` collection model example **pizza, burger**

`Category` collection model example **lunch, dinner**

`Cuisines` collection model example **italian, mexican**

Now I want to find only those `Recipe` whose  `name` is pizza and

whose collection `name` is `lunch` and

also, should only belong to cuisines name either `Italian` or `Mexican`.

**What is the best way to perform filter query considering performance should not be compromised?**

I can't use denormalization and cannot include `category` and `cuisines` in same `recipe` document because each cuisine and category type must be a unique also each has `many to many` relations with `Recipe` thus denormalizing for this condition is not well suited here.

I am using loopback-datasource-juggler orm for Mongo

which creates a separate table handling `many to many relationship` structure.

`Recipe`

```
{
   RECIPE_ID,
   RECIPE_NAME,
   ....
   ....
}
```

`Category`

```
{
  CATEGORY_ID,
  CATEGORY_NAME
}
```

//Connecting both Recipe and Category model

`RecipeCategory`

```
{
  RECIPE_ID
  CATEGORY_ID
}
```

`Cuisines`

```
{
  CUISINES_ID,
  CUISINES_NAME
}
```

//Connecting both `Recipe` and `Cuisines` model

`RecipeCuisines`

```
{
  RECIPE_ID
  CUISINES_ID
}
```

That how loopback-datasource-juggler an orm for node.js is creating model in case of `many to many` relation.

**Now how should i perform a filter query that will find only those `Recipe` whose  `name` is pizza and whose collection `name` is `lunch` and also, should only belong to cuisines name either `Italian` or `Mexican` using mongoDb?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use imbedded documents to solve this problem.

A recipe collection (assume `category` and `cuisines` fields should be small)

```
{
   _id: xx
   name: "pizza",
   category: ["lunch", "dinner"],
   cuisines: ["italian", "mexican"]
}
```

Query

```
db.recipe.find({name: "pizza", category: "lunch", cusisines: "mexican"})
```

You can also create proper index to speed up your query.

Comment: thanks for your answer but as I said in my question embedding is not possible in this case.  Category and cuisines are unique field and should be distinct also is connected with many to many relationship using a third join table